# gapi.auth.authorize: TypeError: cv(...) is null

Tags: javascript, client, authorize

My web applicaion uses `google` javascript client APIs and it dosen't work now.

An error message occured in `Firefox` console like:  `TypeError: cv(...) is null`

has anyone met this problem?

Comment: same here. error appeared today.

Comment: I had the same problem today :/ Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Google has fixed the issue and the api works as expected again.

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=110